# Using void to calculate binary number

Tags: c

If I am using `void numberToBinary(int binaryArr[], int numberOfElements)` to convert a number to a binary number how would I go about doing that? I tried a code I used from an earlier lab, and it did not work with the program. I am confused on what to put with the void part. Currently my output is just saying Binary:
There is nothing printing after the binary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

void numberToBinary(int arr[], int numOfBits, int userNum);
void addOne(int arr[], int numOfBits);
void flipBits(int arr[], int numOfBits);
void printArray(int binaryArr[], int numberOfElements);
void binaryToLED(int binaryArr[], int numOfBits, int pinNumbers[]);

int main(void) {
    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1) {
        puts("Raspberry Pi setup failed. Check the wiringPi library. ");
        return 1;
    }
    int numOfBits;
    printf("How many bits? ");
    scanf("%d", &numOfBits);
    
    int pinNumbers[numOfBits];
    int userPin;
    for (int i = 0; i< numOfBits; i++) {
        printf("Enter the pin number for LED %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &userPin);
        pinNumbers[i] = userPin;
        pinMode(pinNumbers[i], OUTPUT);
    }
    
    int binaryArr[numOfBits];
    int upperBound = 16;
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int userNum;
    
    printf("\n                                                    \n%38s", "Number to Binary Converter");
    printf("\n                                                    \n%44s", "Enter number between 127 and -128 to be converted to binary. Enter a non-numeric input to end.");
    printf("\n                                                    \n\n");
    
    while(scanf("%d", &userNum) ==1) {
        if((userNum < lowerBound) || userNum > upperBound) {
            printf("%d is out of range. \n", userNum);
            printf("Enter a number within -127, 128 to be respresented.");
            continue;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfBits; i++) {
            binaryArr[i] = 0;
        }
        numberToBinary(binaryArr, numOfBits, abs(userNum));
        if (userNum < 0) {
            flipBits(binaryArr, numOfBits);
            addOne(binaryArr, numOfBits);
        }
        printf("Binary: ");
        printArray(binaryArr, numOfBits);
        puts("");
        
        binaryToLED(binaryArr, numOfBits, pinNumbers);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void addOne(int arr[], int numOfBits){
}
void printArray(int binaryArr[], int numberOfElements) {
    int i;
}
void numberToBinary(int binaryArr[], int numOfBits, int userNum) {

}
void flipBits(int binaryArr[], int numOfBits){
    for(int i = 0; i< numOfBits; i++){
        if(binaryArr[i] ==1) {
            binaryArr[i] ++;
        }
    }
    return;
}
void binaryToLED(int binaryArr[], int numOfBits, int pinNumbers[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfBits; i++) {
        digitalWrite(pinNumbers[i], binaryArr[i]);
    }
    delay(5000);
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfBits; i++) {
        digitalWrite(pinNumbers[i], 0);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Certainly better. Would help to include a specific use-case that has you stumped, as there's a lot of ways this could be used if we were to test it. For example, should `binaryArr` contain a series of values like `1` or `0` or ASCII characters like `'1'` or `'0'`? Maybe `sprintf` is the answer here. Maybe not!

Comment: @tadman It is suppose to contain values not characters.

Comment: Easy approach: `sprintf` into a buffer, then iterate over that, converting to numbers as in `c-'0'`. Better approach: Bitshifting and bitmasking.

Comment: @tadman is there anyway you can show how to do that?

Comment: It looks like you need to get more comfortable with operations like `(1<<n)` and `x&y`. Simple bit test: `x&(1<<n)` will return non-zero if that bit *n* is set, zero otherwise. Easy way to convert that to 1/0 is just `(x&(1<<n)) ? 1 : 0)` or `!!(x&(1<<n))`

Comment: `"Enter a number within -127, 128 to be respresented."` in unusual.  I'd expect `"Enter a number within -128, 127 to be represented."`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do in the numberToBinary() function. Do you want to convert a decimal number to binary?

Comment: Yes, exactly @AustinHe

Comment: @KatieS And you limit the decimal number from 0 to 16, right?

Comment: @AustinHe No, I did not know what to put for it.

Answer (score 0):

> convert a number to a binary number

Only a single integer needed.

```
#define ON_TIME 5000
void binaryToLED(unsigned number, int numOfBits), int pinNumbers[]) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i<numOfBits; i++) {
    digitalWrite(pinNumbers[i] , number & 1);
    numer >>= 1;
  }
  delay(ON_TIME);
  for (i = 0; i<numOfBits; i++) {
    digitalWrite(pinNumbers[i] , 0);
  }
}

// Pass in address of the integer
void flipBits(unsigned *number, int numOfBits){
  if (numOfBits > 0) {
    unsigned mask = 1u << (numOfBits-1);;
    *number ^= mask;
  }
}
```

Comment: So I can just get rid of the other voids? @chux

Comment: @KatieS Still need ` printArray()`